# Using regex to retrieve specific text

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, twitter

```
tweets = re.findall(r "'text':+.*'truncated'", tweets)

print (tweets)
```

> 'text': "RT @premierleague:  @WayneRooney's chase is on ", 'truncated':

I have a string of text like above and I want to retrieve the tweet which is in between `'text': and 'truncated'`.

I have written the above code but receive the error message

```
 tweets = re.findall(r "'text':+.*'truncated'", tweets)
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am using `findall` as the tweets are repeated and I want to retrieve all the tweets from the `findall` search.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you do not want to exploit the json structure of your string and use the `json` module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invalid syntax error is due to the **white space between `r` and the regex**:

```
tweets = re.findall(r"'text':+.*'truncated'", tweets)
print(tweets)
```

returns:

```
['\'text\': "RT @premierleague: \xf0\x9f\x94\xb5 @WayneRooney\'s chase is on \xf0\x9f\x91\x80", \'truncated\'']
```

To retrieve only the text:

```
tweets = re.findall(r"'text':+(.*)'truncated'", tweets)
print(tweets)
```

returns:

```
 "RT @premierleague:  @WayneRooney's chase is on ",
```

Comment: Yes, and you can use round brakets to get the text too.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up r.e. the white space. I expected that it would then remove all the text that I didn't want however it just returned the api search.

Comment: @LukeSimpson I updated the answer above to retrieve only the text. Note that it would probably be easier to just parse the JSON if that's possible (with `json.loads` in Python).

Comment: @LukeSimpson Do you want me to detail something to accept the answer?

Comment: Hi, yes please. It still isn't the case that only the text in between text and truncated is retrieved.

Comment: I'm not sure I see what you mean. That's what the second regex in my answer does.